# To-Do list which could read the task on time

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, reminders, clock, voice

I'm looking for the application for OS X (Maverick), which could merge two tasks for me. 
One is the TO-DO list just like "Reminders".
The second one is more tricky - I wish "Reminders" to read task on loud as soon as the task will be close to specific time frame.

I use similar functionality in the OSX's clock, which tells me each 15 minutes what time is it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for an OS X app or an iOS app?

Comment: @grgarside, I'm looking for the OSX app.